# Generate a table based on a selection from a dynamic drop down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

so I am learning ASP.NET currently and actually today is my second day.

So right now I am wanting to create a page where I have first a dynamically generated dropdown that selects just the first name from my database and table. This I have working

Next I have a gridview table that shows all the data from the database, currently I have hard coded a name so the page will not crash (there are 100000 rows of data)

Lastly when I post my code you will see a checkbox, that is just so when I click it the gridview will show up. I am just trying that out, because that was part of a lesson I learned today.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Test of First Database pull</h1>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text="Show Panel" OnCheckedChanged="checkbox1_CheckedChanged" />
        <br />
         <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="FirstName" DataValueField="FirstName" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASP.NETConnectionString1 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASP.NETConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [FirstName] FROM [SampleData] ORDER BY 'FirstName' "></asp:SqlDataSource>

         <br />
         <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False" >
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SSN" HeaderText="SSN" SortExpression="SSN" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HomeStreet" HeaderText="HomeStreet" SortExpression="HomeStreet" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HomeCity" HeaderText="HomeCity" SortExpression="HomeCity" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HomeState" HeaderText="HomeState" SortExpression="HomeState" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HomeZip" HeaderText="HomeZip" SortExpression="HomeZip" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyStreet" HeaderText="CompanyStreet" SortExpression="CompanyStreet" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyCity" HeaderText="CompanyCity" SortExpression="CompanyCity" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyState" HeaderText="CompanyState" SortExpression="CompanyState" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyZip" HeaderText="CompanyZip" SortExpression="CompanyZip" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HomePhone" HeaderText="HomePhone" SortExpression="HomePhone" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyPhone" HeaderText="CompanyPhone" SortExpression="CompanyPhone" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CellPhone" HeaderText="CellPhone" SortExpression="CellPhone" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfBirth" HeaderText="DateOfBirth" SortExpression="DateOfBirth" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfHire" HeaderText="DateOfHire" SortExpression="DateOfHire" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASP.NETConnectionString1 %>" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASP.NETConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [SSN], [LastName], [FirstName], [HomeStreet], [HomeCity], [HomeState], [HomeZip], [CompanyName], 
                [CompanyStreet], [CompanyCity], [CompanyState], [CompanyZip], [HomePhone], [CompanyPhone], [CellPhone], 
                [DateOfBirth], [DateOfHire] FROM [SampleData] WHERE [FirstName] = 'Bob' "></asp:SqlDataSource>


        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my C# part where i call the session

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Demos_GridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          string name = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
           Session["FName"] = name;
    }
    protected void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

As you see I called the session "I believe" I tried using this

```
 <%:Session["user"]%>
```

within that sql query but it was saying I could not have the <%%> within the asp sql calling. 
So if anyone could help me out that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add the name of the user as a `SqlParameter`?

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", name));
// Of course don't forget to edit your query: WHERE [FirstName] = @Name
```

Something as the above should work (note I haven't tested it).

**Edit:**

You could shorten this process even more by configuring your SqlDataSource to set the `@Name` parameter's value from a `Control` or `Session`.

Comment: Which file should I add that first code in the the aspx page? or the cs page?

Comment: You should add this in the code-behind (.cs). Anyway, I suggest you to follow my last advice, which is better.

Comment: Thanks man, I tried it put it was not working, but I found if I edited the data source of my grid view, I could just use the wizard and tell what the where clause to do and then I had to set my drop down to an auto post back so every time it changed I would get said result.